# Is Hashem spiritual?

Tags: theology, time

I know that Hashem is not physical but is He spiritual? Also does He exist in time?

Comment: HaShem is an eternal Spirit; and time does not exist in eternity. Time is an accident of motion. Since we cannot imagine HaShem as a moving Being, time is not an appropriate term to use in relation to G-d. The only way to relate with G-d is in a spiritual manner. I mean, esoterically.

Comment: This question is dependent on a couple of vague terms that would need to be defined to make it a meaningful and answerable question: "spiritual" and "exist in time." I'm closing the question pending such definitions.

Comment: In The Elucidated Derech Hashem by Rabbi Abba Zvi Naiman
on page 131 chapter 5 footnote 2:
"In Daas Tevunos (§78) and Pischei Chochmah VeDaas (§101), the Ramchal also divides creation into physical and spiritual beings. This classification, of course, refers to the beings Hashem has created. Hashem, the Creator, is neither physical nor spiritual. He is beyond any of these classifications. See also further on, note 42."

Answer (score 2):

my (simplistic) understanding is that G-d created time and space, and he also created the human mind with an inability to understand anything that exists without those limits. It is therefore impossible to define Him within our limitations.

Answer (score 1):

He isn't spiritual or physical. i dont think its possible to know what he is.

Comment: HaShem is what He is. And to know Him is all that life is about. The more we know of Him, it is only the beginning of knowledge. (Prov. 1:7)

Answer (score 0):

Wayon is quoting what is called Negative theology but to be more exact he is and is not The reason HE IS NOT IS BECAUSE BY ASCRIBING A character TO HASHEM IS IN TERMS Limiting HIM hence he IS NOT BUT HE IS ALSO.

Comment: again i AM NOT ARGUING WITH WAYON just ADDING

Comment: Moses Maimonides, BTW, asserts that, one usually comes one step nearer to the knowledge of God by using negative Theology. I mean, by applying negative attributes to Him. I understand by this that 
HaShem is what He is whithout what makes us be what we are. In G-d it is all in His essence. In us it is all an accident of matter.

Comment: It's important to always bear in mind that human language is inadequate for discussing God. After all, God is not really a "Him." Referring to God as "Him" implies that God has a physical male body. Again, my point is that our language does not even allow for talking about God without imposing human values and characteristics on God.

Answer (score 0):

HaShem is not physical, as He is Incorporeal. G-d exists for all eternity; and time does not exist in eternity. We cannot think of HaShem in terms of time because time is an accident of motion. Since G-d is incorporeal, and motion is an accident of matter, we cannot think of His moving from place to place, therefore.